# How to make input text field replace any character by *?

Tags: html, input

I am working on a site where user authentication is used. When user submits the authentication form, browser asks if user wants to remember password. I think that "feature" is very annoying, so I need to tell every browser not to remember that password. I don't want to use AJAX authentication, also autocomplete="off" doesn't work. So I need  to hide characters replacing them by *.

Comment: You're allowed to think that browser password caching is "annoying". Your users are also allowed to think that you are completely ridiculous and totally abandon your site. Unless you can give a more compelling reason than your annoyance, you're unlikely to get any help on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad idea and not very easily enforceable.  There are registry settings you can push as group policy to enforce browsers to not cache passwords.  Group policy can also make it impossible for the user to install any browser other than IE.  In fact, just don't allow the user to install anything, just in case they happen to download some password management software that interfaces with modern browsers.  Heck, policy can even implement registry hacks to prevent IE from displaying multiple tabs so that it "looks" like older versions of browsers if that is what your users desire.  Sorry I sound bitter.  I've been in an environment like this.

As for an actual answer.  The one option you do not like is:

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Another is to have a standard `<input type="text" />` and use javascript and the keypress event to change any characters into *'s and capture the real value in a hidden field.